# What is Received Sequence Counter(RSC) in WPA authentication

Tags: authentication, wifi, wpa2, 802.1x

In WPA 4-way handshake and in Message 3  (while GTK transfer),  A RSC (Received sequence Number ) sent by the Authenticator (AP) to the supplicant.
The only information I found about RSC is that it's the starting sequence Number for GTK.

How is it generated and How is it relevant for the supplicant?